# Inline CSS is not working correctly in iPhone

Tags: html, css

I have created the below HTML content using TinyMCE Editor and preview in iPhone webview.

I need to show the content in Orange color with `tahoma,arial,helvetica,sans-serif` family and size is `10pt`. The below HTML code is working perfectly in a desktop browser, but the same code is not working on the iPhone.

Could you please suggest what the issue with the HTML could be?

**Working HTML Code**

```
<p style="text-align: left;"><span style="font-size: 10pt;"><strong><span style="font-family: tahoma,arial,helvetica,sans-serif; color: #ff9900;">HEALTH</span></strong></span></p>
```

**Not Working HTML Code**

```
<p style="text-align: left;"><span style="color: #ff9900; font-size: 10pt;"><strong><span style="font-family: tahoma,arial,helvetica,sans-serif;">DENTAL</span></strong></span></p>
```

Comment: Ummm... Can you please include the HTML? The code itself is not showing up.

Comment: ...so the only difference is the position of `color`? Also, you say: "same code is not working" > and than you show two *Different* codes... :D

Comment: "Not working" is not a technical term. Also, pt is for print, not the web.

Comment: Yes, "not working" is too vague. Remember that Tahoma isn't an iPhone font, too.